# Xpath for HTML UnitDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to get the xpath for my HTMLUnitDriver test to find Username

```
<div class="form-group" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0">
<label class="control-label" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$label"> <span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.$label.1">Username</span></label> 
<input type="text" label="Username" class="form-control" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1:$input"></div>
```

I tried following -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for = 'Username']"))
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[label[contains(., 'Username')]]"))
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/form/div[1]/input"))
```

but none of them seems to work. I am using Selenium Geb with Groovy Spock. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `//input[@label='Username']`

Comment: @PankajJaju that didnot work

Comment: Maybe because your input tag is not closed and hence your xml parser is throwing error. Can you confirm if the HTML is properly structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Geb but are not using any of the Geb syntax. Your page elements should be defined within the content block of your page object like so:

```
class MyPage extends Page {

  static content = {

    username $("span", text: contains("Username"))

    //alternatively do it this way
    username { find("span", text: "Username") }

  }

}
```

Comment: Rushby, yes you are right, I was not using the Geb syntax. thanks for pointing it out. This worked!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, It will Work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@data-reactid='.0.1.0.0.$label']//span[@data-reactid='.0.1.0.0.$label.1'][contains(text(),'Username')]"));
```